# Why does PHP convert String to Integer?

Tags: php, string, comparison, integer

I would like to know on what condition PHP decides when to convert from String to Integer and the other way around

Example:

```
$key = 0;
$test = 'teststring';
if($key == $test) {
    echo "Why, tell me why!";
}
else {
    echo "That's the way love goes...";
}
```

I know I should use '===' to get better results, but I'm curious to know why PHP decides to convert the string to integer and not the other way around.

Comment: Read this : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It converts strings to numbers when either operand is a number. The manual puts it cryptically like this:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> For various types, comparison is done according to the following table (in order).
>
> ```
> Operand 1           Operand 2
>
> null or string      string              Convert NULL to "", numerical
>                                         or lexical comparison
> ...
>
> string, resource    string, resource    Translate strings and resources
> or number           or number           to numbers, usual math
> ```

*Note that the "in order" part is important when reading this table.*

Answer (score 5):

From the PHP Manual:

> a variable's type is determined by the context in which the variable is used. That is to say, if a string value is assigned to variable $var, $var becomes a string. If an integer value is then assigned to $var, it becomes an integer.

See [Type Juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and [Type Comparison Table](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) and [String conversion to numbers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)  for details:

> If the string does not contain any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E' and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by PHP_INT_MAX), the string will be evaluated as an integer. In all other cases it will be evaluated as a float.
>
> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an 'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.

And the [chapter on Strings:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> An integer or float is converted to a string representing the number textually (including the exponent part for floats). Floating point numbers can be converted using exponential notation (4.1E+6).

And also (was already given by deceze though) the [chapter on Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

Comment: Very good, but the question was *why from string to integer* and not the other way around. @deceze seems to have answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual

> When a string is evaluated in a numeric context, the resulting value and type are determined as follows.
>
> If the string does not contain any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E' and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by PHP_INT_MAX), the string will be evaluated as an integer. In all other cases it will be evaluated as a float.
>
> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an 'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Answer (score -1):

Because thats the way they designed the language, as described [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).